# Universal Windows Platform (UWP) write image to disk sectors

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, disk, writefile

There are alot of examples of writing files to disk using UWP apis but is it possible to write an image file (.img) to disk using UWP apis + c# much in the same way [win32DiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/p/win32diskimager/code/ci/master/tree/) does?

Answer (score 1):

There is no UWP API can operate .img file. For C#, you can try with 
[.NET DiscUtils](http://discutils.codeplex.com/). DiscUtils is a .NET library to read and write ISO files. However this library still can't be used in UWP apps.

So I'm afraid it's impossible to write an image file (.img) to disk using UWP APIs + C#.